# Can Maple handle subgroups of infinite index?

Tags: maple

I am starting with Maple. I want to look at different subgroups $\mathbb{Z} \le \mathbb{Z}^3$.

I tried to create them in Maple 2018 but it threw some error at me saying there are too many cosets. Can Maple not do this?

Maybe this isn't the right place to ask this question. If so can someone point me to an appropriate place?

Comment: Your best best is www.mapleprimes.com the high activity user forum run by Maplesoft itself.